# Connecting via hostname using socket works, but not for all ports

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I wanted to see how sockets work, so I skimmed through the [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto) and the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html) and tried to write my own code. The server side looks like this:

```
ssock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
assert socket.gethostname() == HOST
ssock.bind((HOST, PORT))
ssock.listen(5)
while True:
    csock, address = ssock.accept()
    print('Accepted connection from', address)
    t = threading.Thread(target=server, args=(csock,))
    t.start()
```

The client side is:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

Those are in one module, so constants are the same. This doesn't work. When I try to connect, I get a `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`.

**HOWEVER**:

1. When I try to connect via the hostname to another port, it works:

   ```
   In [4]: s.connect((HOST, 22))

   In [5]: s.recv(1024)
   Out[5]: b'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1\r\n'
   ```

   (obviously, it's not my app handling the connection on the server).
2. When I change the host name to the local IP address in the server code, I can connect to my port, too (using IP as the host string).

The combination of these circumstances puzzles me. Can anyone explain this behavior?

**EDIT:** seems like I can connect with `HOST` if I use the IP in the server code, too. But why doesn't it work like in the HOWTO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to "" instead of HOST:

```
ssock.bind(("", PORT))
```

Comment: From the HOWTO: "If we had used `s.bind(('', 80))` [...] we would still have a “server” socket, but one that was only visible within the same machine." -- isn't that correct?

Comment: "" and "0.0.0.0" should bind to all available interfaces.
`ss -lntp` is really useful to list listening sockets.

Comment: It indeed does work, you and @t-8ch are right, and the HOWTO isn't, at least the way I understand it. Thanks. I think I should mark this one as accepted then.

Comment: In case you haven't come across it already, http://twistedmatrix.com/ is a good resource for network programming.